# When to malloc() memory for an array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

There's a struct

```
struct Foo{
    int a, b, c;
    char* name;
};
```

with an initialization function

```
Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, const char* name){
    // ... stuff
}
```

When I create a `struct Foo` object, I pass in a `const char*`, to serve as the object's name. Example:

```
struct Foo foo1;
Foo_init(&foo1, "foo1");
```

The goal is to "store" the content of `"foo1"` into `foo1`'s `char*` variable.

I'm currently doing it like:

```
Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, const char* name){
    foo->name = name;

    // ... other stuff
}
```

but I wonder if the correct way is:

```
Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, const char* name){
    int name_len = strlen(name) + 1;
    foo->name = malloc(name_len);
    memcpy(foo->name, name, name_len)

    // ... other stuff
}
```

(I suppose either way is fine, since in this example the argument `"foo1"` is a string literal.)

1. Which way is correct?
2. What if the argument `const char* name` is no longer a string literal, but an arbitrary array with length determined at runtime?
3. What if the signature of `Foo_init()` is not `Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, const char* name)` but `Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, char* name)` (ie. the `char*` is no longer `const`)?
4. More generally, *when* do I need to `malloc()`/`memcpy()` memory for an incoming argument that is a `char*` (or an `int*`, or anything that owns a bunch of elements in memory), assuming I want "store it" inside a `struct`?

Comment: You specifically **do not have** an array **inside** the struct. You have a *pointer*

Comment: The "correct" way depends on whether you want the struct to *own* the data or not.

Comment: Detail: Use `size_t` --> `size_t name_len = strlen(name) + 1;`

Comment: `foo->name = name;` should have warned about losing `const`.  Certainly this is not correct code.

Comment: What's wrong with using strdup() to allocate and copy a string in one line of code that's easy to read?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: As `strdup()` isn't C but POSIX it might not be available.

Comment: It is very rare that one program is written for both a PC and a wrist-watch.  Even more rare than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which way is correct?

It depends on usecase, but *highly* prefer **second**. If you would store a pointer to string literal to `name` and then tried to modify its content, it would lead to undefined behavior. If `name` was `const`, and you would just need to store this `string` without modification, you could use first.

A common technique is for `string` literals to be put in "*read-only-data*" section which gets mapped into the process space as read-only (which is why you can't change it). It does vary by platform.

> What if the argument const char* name is no longer a string literal,
>   but an arbitrary array with length determined at runtime?

Doesn't matter, it will be the same. If its `string` (null terminated sequence of characters), `strlen` will return number of characters and you can copy it to malloced memory on `heap`.

> What if the signature of Foo_init() is not Foo_init(struct Foo* foo,
>   const char* name) but Foo_init(struct Foo* foo, char* name) (ie. the
>   char* is no longer const)?

It's no longer `const`. It allows you to modify content of an array. Since you dont need to modify it (it's init function), you should leave it `const`.

> More generally, when do I need to malloc()/memcpy() memory for an
>   incoming argument that is a char* (or an int*, or anything that owns a
>   bunch of elements in memory), assuming I want "store it" inside a
>   struct?

You need allocate memory with *dynamic storage duration* on heap when you dont know amount of input data and need to calculate it in runtime.
Automatic arrays are safer & faster so if you dont have to use *dynamic storage*, dont.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you. In general I prefer zero-copy over nonzero-copy, but in this case I'm still trying to convince myself that _not_ using the `memcpy()` approach is actually safe...